# Differentes results Linux Windows to readExcel with Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am reading a Excel with Java in my localhost with Windows, then I generated .war and upload this code to server Linux, but I get differents results --->

My code have 2000 lines->

```
switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                LOGGER.info("CELL_TYPE_FORMULA");
                try {
                    LOGGER.info("Intentar parsear la formula");
                    stringValue = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(cell.getNumericCellValue())
                            .replaceAll("\\.", "");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // El resultado de la formula es ' - ' , eso no se puede parsear.
                    LOGGER.error("------------------------------------------------------------");
                    LOGGER.error("------------------------------------------------------------");
                    LOGGER.error("El resultado de la formula es ' - ' , no se puede parsear.");
                    LOGGER.error("Error previsible y controlado.");
                    LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage() + ex);
                    LOGGER.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                    LOGGER.error("------------------------------------------------------------");
                    LOGGER.error("------------------------------------------------------------");

                    stringValue = null;
                }
                break;

        }
```

When I read this with Windows I  get ->

[image]

In linux ->

[image]

In my country `"."` is thousands `","` is decimal...

Someome can say " You can do replaceALL "," for "" But in my country "," is very important...

Problems with ->

```
  stringValue = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(cell.getNumericCellValue())
```

Excel ->

[image]

In my country is "36Millons"

I use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
```

In windows is ok but in Linux I get other result ...
In windows I lose "." the Thousands, but I do not care, however is **dangerous** when Linux change "." for ","

Ty

Comment: See [Getting the cell contents](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents). Instead of `stringValue = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(cell.getNumericCellValue())` do `... DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(new Locale("es", "ES")); ... stringValue = formatter.formatCellValue(cell); ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NumberFormat correctNumberFormatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("en", "US"));
```

Try to create NumberFormater with Locale Object in Constructor.

Here is a list of supported Locales:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html
(You can choose different combinations of Lang and Country, for example: en_GB, en_US, ja_JP)

How Number Format is working with different Locales:

```
123 456   fr_FR
123.456   de_DE
123,456   en_US
```

Comment: new Locale("es_ES"), now Windows ->> 36,500,000  fail

Comment: I was wrong. Try new Locale("es", "ES"); - it`s correct constructor for Locale

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html

Comment: Using `apache poi`'s [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) will be the better approach.